# Command "make:seeder" is not defined in laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

Getting error :

[InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "make:seeder" is not defined.
  Did you mean one of these?
      db:seed
      make:migration
      make:controller
      make:middleware
      make:request
      make:provider
      make:console
      make:event
      make:model
      make:command

My laravel version is 5.0. I have run php artisan make:seeder SettingTableSeeder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `make:seeder` artisan call was introduced in Laravel 5.1, so you'll have to write them manually or upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The `php artisan make:seeder` command is introduced in Laravel 5.1, so it will not work in Laravel 5.0

You need to run another command:

> To seed your database, you may use the `db:seed` command on the Artisan CLI: `php artisan db:seed`
>
> By default, the `db:seed` command runs the `DatabaseSeeder` class, which may be used to call other seed classes. However, you may use the `--class` option to specify a specific seeder class to run individually: `php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder`
>
> You may also seed your database using the `migrate:refresh` command, which will also rollback and re-run all of your migrations: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Taken from the Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#database-seeding

---

**How to create a seeding**

> Laravel also includes a simple way to seed your database with test data using seed classes. All seed classes are stored in `database/seeds`. Seed classes may have any name you wish, but probably should follow some sensible convention, such as `UserTableSeeder`, etc. By default, a `DatabaseSeeder` class is defined for you. From this class, you may use the `call` method to run other seed classes, allowing you to control the seeding order.

Add this to a file in `database/seeds/seedsfilename.php`.

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(['email' => 'foo@bar.com']);
    }

}
```

After that you need to run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload` (it does the same but only another name).

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to make/create seeder table

Comment: Thank you for reply so in last we have to create our own right ? @Robin Dirksen